SAS day of week name to char (downame.)
I have a date variable and want to create a new variable with the name of the day of the week.
I use the following for this.
a.date format=DOWNAME. AS DayOfWeek

date       | DayOfWeek
-----------------------
25/06/2024 | Tuesday

However, if I export this to Excel the date is exported instead of the name of the day.
How can I convert the name of the day to text (character variable) so that it is exported as text to Excel?

I found the solution myself. It's actually very simple.
PUT(A.date, DOWNAME.) AS DayOfWeek


Be careful as the DOWNAME format will right align the value by default.  If you do not want all of those leading spaces then use the -L modifier on the format specification. PUT(A.date, DOWNAME.-L) AS DayOfWeek

Do you know you can format a date as you want?
=TEXT(B2;"dddd")

This formula just shows you the name of that day ("dinsdag", in Dutch, in my case, should be "Tuesday" for you).

Can I also do this via Powershell. My SAS export is also processed by a Powerhell script and I have to execute it there.

@JohnDoe: I heavily doubt that: as far as I know, there's not link between Excel and Powershell functions.

There is : Import-Excel and Export-Excel

@JohnDoe: never heard of this, but it looks fascinating.
